# destroy the current page when navigating to another page using StackNavigator and stop all running process on previous page

Tags: javascript, react-native, stack-navigator

I'm using react-native, when I try to navigate to another page using `StackNavigator` the previous page is running on the background

This is App.js

```
import Login from './app/component/Login';
import Menu from './app/component/Menu';
import Guide from './app/component/additions/Guide';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const Navigator = StackNavigator({
  login: {screen: Login},
  main: {screen: Menu},
  guide: {screen: Guide},
},{ headerMode: 'none' });
```

And I have a Guid.js like this

```
componentDidMount() {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('I do not leak');
  }, 1000);
}

render() {
  const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('main')}>
      <Text> navigate to main </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

The problem is, even I navigate to the `main` page, I still getting the interval that I log inside the `componentDidMount` of my Guide.js, and even going back on that page, it runs the `componentDidMount` and run again my log, that means the interval is running again, what I want to do is after or while navigating to another page, I want to destroy the Guide.js, the page where I came from, and I have a page where I run `WebView` I wan't to do the same thing for that page, how can I do that?

Comment: It sounds like you need to clear the interval on `componentDidUnmount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once timers are set, they runs asynchronously, you have to remove the timer if it's no longer needed when you leave the screen, like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.timerID = null;
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('I do not leak');
    }, 1000);
}

/**
 * Frees up timer if it is set.
 */
componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.timerID != null) {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load components only when they are needed by using the new React-native Lazy API, here is some documentation on how to use: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html